# Inifnispan server stop responding (near cache configured , clustered environment, client server configuration)

Tags: caching, infinispan

We have been facing infinispan server issue while we are testing our application with 100 concurrent active session each cluster node of our application.

Infinispan server configuration.

Two Domain with Two node
Near Cache is configured,INVALIDATE type , with no max entry limit.
our Application is having two cluster node as well.
Infinispan version : 8.2.3

Error we are finding in infinispan server:

```
2017-06-08 18:49:18,464 DEBUG [org.infinispan.server.hotrod.HotRodExceptionHandler] (HotRodServerWorker-8-7) Exception caught: java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
  at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read0(Native Method)
  at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:43)
  at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:223)
  at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:192)
  at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:380)
  at io.netty.buffer.PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.setBytes(PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.java:221)
  at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.writeBytes(AbstractByteBuf.java:898)
  at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doReadBytes(NioSocketChannel.java:242)
  at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:119)
  at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:528)
  at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:485)
  at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:399)
  at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:371)
  at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:112)
  at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:137)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

After getting this error, we tried disabling near cache with infinispan server. That configuration get the things correct but It also result in very slow performance which is not acceptable as we are using infinispan server for performance purpose only.

Our Template using which we are creating cache container in Infinispan

```
  <distributed-cache-configuration name="OurTempateName" owners="2" segments="20" mode="SYNC" remote-timeout="30000" start="EAGER">
                    <locking striping="false" acquire-timeout="30000" concurrency-level="1000"/>
                    <transaction mode="NONE"/>
                    <security/>
                </distributed-cache-configuration>
```

With Client server infinispan setup, Can anyone suggest configuration which can overcome this issue?

Comment: Cross posted [here](https://developer.jboss.org/message/972992?et=watches.email.thread#972992).

Answer (score 0):

If you see that kind of messages, they might indicate that there is some problem with the client. Did you look into client logs?

Comment: This is not really an answer but a question. More suited for a question comment than an actual answer.

Comment: Also, note that the question has been cross posted, so let's focus efforts on Infinispan forums.